# calling xcode method from javascript function to and get returned value

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios5

im developing an app, which **requires to load some menu's and presentations(pdf, flash etc.)**
menu items are loaded from database and each contains ID and Text. Menu items looks like below:

Crocin
Combiflame

**above menu items are hyper links, clicking them will open up presentations on the same page.**

i need to call a xcode method in this scenario which can query database (located in document folder in app) and return presentation name and some other details.

i got two problems here

1) i came across

```
**– webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:**
```

but **this method returns BOOL** and i **want to return Presentation with other information**

2) no idea how can i load presentation (inside Resources Folder of my app ) via javascript on the same page.

Any suggestions will b greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can do pretty much what you need in `webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType`.

1. If you return `NO` from it, then the web view will not load the current request; this will make your app free of doing whatever it needs:
2. you can then either load a different request in the same web view (say an HTML string that embeds the presentation resource),
3. or, you can send a message to some controller of yours to run a different workflow altogether (display a different kind of view or whatever).

EDIT:

elaborating more option 2:

1. say that you have a view controller which embed the UIWebView and also acts as delegate for it;
2. you could define a method in the view controller which gets and HTML string and loads it into the web view, like this:

   ```
   - (void)loadContentInWebView:(NSString*)content {
        [_webView loadHTMLString:content  baseURL:nil];
   }
   ```
3. now, in `webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType`, you could do something like this:

   ```
   - (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView*)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
           if ([[[request URL] absoluteString] isEqual:WHATEVER]) {
                [self loadContentInWebView:HERE_THE_HTML];
                return NO;
       }
       return YES;
   }
   ```

What you should define here is:

```
 ([[[request URL] absoluteString] isEqual:WHATEVER])
```

i.e., the logics to understand when the user touched some link that should make a presentation loaded;

and:

```
  [self loadContentInWebView:HERE_THE_HTML];
```

i.e., define in some way the HTML content that you want to use so to have the presentation displayed.

Comment: **you can then either load a different request in the same web view (say an HTML string that embeds the presentation resource)**
 

This is what i want to do. Bt not clear how!!!

i have <embed> tag inside my webview (which is displaying HTML5 page) but how can i change its Src attribute in

**webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType** method ?? any link resource where same thing has been done...

Comment: Please, see my edit... you do not change the src attribute, you return NO (initial request is aborted) and create a new one.

Answer (score 0):

i got a work around..although it is not a good practice:

in model:
**This method gets called whenever a request comes for this webview even when the page loads in webview**

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
    // check the request, if it's ajax callback, just return NO; other wise YES;


//    NSURLRequest *request = [self request];
    NSURL *url = [request URL];

    NSString *file = [url lastPathComponent];
    if ([file isEqualToString:@"Presentation.html"] == YES) {
        return YES;
    }

    if ([file isEqualToString:@"ajaxcallback.htm"] == YES) {
        // that means the ajax call is done, so you can call this 
        NSString *result = [web stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"getResponse();"];

        // don't forget to stop loading this fake page
        return NO;
    }
}
```

and in javascript:

```
   function sendRequestToApp(){
        window.location="http://www.domain.com/ajaxcallback.htm";
    }

    function getResponse(src){
        alert("response");
        document.getElementById("sample").src=src;
    }
```